# Something bad happened while switch to full site after attempt to submit empty post in mobile version

Tags: bug, answers, mobile-web

Steps to reproduce:

1. Switch to mobile web (in the footer)
2. Select any question and tap "Post Your Answer" button while post body is clear. You will see an error message **"Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because: Body is missing."**
3. Tap "Full site" link (in the footer)
4. See the following:

> [image: oops]

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog oops... almost 3 years of my broken memory